# Instantiate a top level lazy value based on value we get in a method scala

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

Is there a way to instantiate a top level lazy value based on value we get in a method

```
trait Props {
  val env: String
}

object Exc extends App {
  Foo.getInput("dev")
}

object Foo extends Props {

  lazy val env: String = ???
  
  def getInput(e: String): Unit = {
    //How do I instantiate env with e here
    env = e //this doesn't work
  }

  def exampleMethod() = println(env)
}
```

object Foo has to extend trait Props, so I need to figure out a way how to instantiate the variable env , based on what's passed in the method

Comment: What would you want the result of `Foo.env` to be if `Foo.getInput` hasn't been called yet?

Comment: Related: how do you want multiple invocations of `Foo.getInput` to be handled?

Comment: Your only option with the current design is to use a `private var` and manually expose getters and setters. Then, you may need to custom logic to ensure invariants like what should happen if the setter s called multiple times, what should happen if the getter is called before the setter, etc. You may also need to manage concurrency... In general, it feels like a very bad idea, I would refractor the code to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing to what you want may well be a `Future`, which is the other notable case in the language and standard library where evaluation can be delayed and a result be write-once.

So something like the following

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{ Await, Future, Promise }
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

object Foo extends Props {
  private val envPromise = Promise[String]()

  lazy val env: String = Await.result(envPromise.future, Duration.Inf)

  def getInput(e: String): Unit = {
    envPromise.success(e)
  }
}
```

If `env` is accessed before `getInput` is called, it will block the accessing thread for arbitrarily long until some other thread calls `getInput` (if no other thread does, it's effectively an infinite loop).  Alternatively one can put a finite duration (e.g. `3.minutes`) on the `Await`, which will throw an exception if `getInput` hasn't been called in that time.  The exception in the `lazy` initializer will propagate to the accessing thread (which may be a bit of a surprise: someone given a `Props` would reasonably expect that accessing the `env` (a `val`) would not blow up), but a subsequent access after `getInput` was called will have the value.

Multiple calls to `getInput` will throw exceptions because a `Promise` can be completed at most one time.

My honest opinion is that it may be worth revisiting the decisions which led up to this.  I would specifically consider some alternative like:

```scala
object Foo {
  private val propsPromise = Promise[Props]()

  val propsFuture: Future[Props] = propsPromise.future

  def getInput(e: String): Unit =
    propsPromise.success(new Props { val env: String = e })
}
```

Where you are delaying construction of a valid `Props` instance but can statically provide a reference to that instance for if/when it exists.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `env` should be `var`:

```scala
var env: String = ???
```

`lazy` here is not needed

Comment: But not sure it's a Scala way.